# Issue in iPad while switching between speaker and Receiver(Ear phone)

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

In My project i want to switch between speaker and Receiver(Head Phones). I am using following code

```
- (IBAction)speakerValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    if(self.speakerSwitch.on) //play through speaker
    {
        UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
        AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,sizeof(category), &category);
    }
    else //play through ear piece
    {
        UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
        AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,sizeof(category), &category);
    }
}
```

In the iPhone it is working fine But in iPad it is not working can any one please suggest.

Regards